# Reading off Socket more quickly than data arrives

Tags: c#, sockets

Here is a simplified version of the ResponseCallback I am using when reading from a `Socket`:

```
private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket target = state.Target;

    int read = target.EndReceive(ar);
    state.Message.AddRange(state.Buffer.Take(read));

    //Console.WriteLine("read: " + read + "\ttarget.Available: " + target.Available);
    //Thread.Sleep(100);

    // If we still have data, keep receiving.
    if (target.Available > 0)
    {
        target.BeginReceive(state, ResponseCallback);
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, we've received the full message; do other processing.
    }
}
```

If I don't have that `Thread.Sleep`, I get the following from `Console.WriteLine`:

> read: 4096 target.Available: 1344
>
> read: 1344 target.Available: 0

With the `Thread.Sleep`, I get the following:

> read: 4096 target.Available: 1344
>
> read: 3100 target.Available: 0

The message is cut off without the `Thread.Sleep` but complete with it.  How can I make sure that I get the full message?  I've tried switching

```
if (target.Available > 0)
```

for

```
if (read > 0)
```

However, `BeginReceive` never ends with a `0` read - which makes sense, since that would mean it hadn't received anything, so it shouldn't end.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't rely on Available. You need to read data until you've received a complete message. How to detect the latter depends on the protocol being used.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what is happening in StateObject, I guess you could read until 0 bytes read, than move on.

Comment: @Darek - `read` will never be 0, because `BeginReceive` won't end in that case.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Is there something that I *can* rely on, or is looking for specific characters or the socket to disconnect the only way?

Comment: @zimdanen I have no clue how and what his Socket works. The sample for System.Net.Sockets.Socket does exactly that, loops until buffer returns 0 bytes.

Comment: No, you can't determine that on the socket. The protocol determines how messages are separated. What protocol is being used?

Comment: @Darek - I don't know what I'm doing differently..

Comment: Closing off. Same issue. Seen 100 times. Sad to see that so many people are mislead by content on the web to use the Available property. It is poison.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  It's TCP.

Comment: I mean the application protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: @usr while technically correct, that answer doesn't say anything. Like demonstrated here, the question _"How to find out if data is available on a socket"_ is not the question OP wants answered, as the answer to that doesn't help them any further. The actual question here is _"How to detect message boundaries"_ or _"How does framing work"_ and I answered that in my first comment: depends on the protocol.

Comment: @CodeCaster you might be right. In any case a duplicate. He'll easily be able to research how to frame messages. No need to explain the 10th time.